# Finding all filenames with containing 1 string but not containing another string

Tags: bash, filenames

I am trying to list all file names that contain a certain string but do not contain another string. For this particular case, I want all filenames containing "*.java" but not "*Test.java". To find and save the first set, I was using:

```
find -name "*.java" > sources.txt
```

But I don't know how to exclude the files that contain "*Test.java" in the file name.
I'm new to bash, so sorry if I've missed something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
find -name "*.java" ! -name "Test.java"
```

Comment: Cool!  I didn't know you could use ! like that for this purpose.

Comment: But beware of the `histexpand` shell option that makes `!` have special meaning.